# How use NULL value SSRS parameter to retrieve rows containing NULLS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, null, where-clause

I've read many posts concerning `NULLS` and SSRS report parameters, but none of them appear to solve my problem.

I have a user-selectable SSRS report parameter `@NoteType` which can be 1, 3, 4 or `NULL`.  The database table I'm working with (`eventText`) has a column `NoteValue` containing 1 of those 4 values.  Unfortunately, I can't alter the table design to substitute an integer for that `NULL` value.

My report works fine if `@NoteType = 1, 3 or 4`; but not if `@NoteType = NULL`.  If `@NoteType = NULL` then, depending on my paramaterized `WHERE` clause (discussed below) my report has either no rows, or it has all of the rows for which `NoteValue = 1, 3 or 4`.  I can't figure out how to retrieve the rows for which `NoteValue = NULL` if the user selects `@NoteType = NULL`.

I've configured the `@NoteType` parameter to allow `NULL` values, with `Note Value` as the parameter's value field and `Note Type` as the label field.  The parameter values are obtained from a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT      ett.NoteValue         AS    [Note Value],
            ett.NoteDescription   AS    [Note Type]
FROM        eventTextType    ett
UNION       
SELECT      NULL                  AS    [Note Value],
            'Blank'               AS    [Note Type]
ORDER BY    [Note Type]
```

The `eventTextType` table has only 3 rows in which the `NoteValue` column value is 1, 3 or 4 respectively.  There is no row with `NoteValue = NULL` in the `eventTextType` table, but there are many such rows in the `eventText` table.  That's why I'm using a `UNION` query to include `NULL` as one of the `@NoteType` parameter values.

The `UNION` query's output is:

```
Note Value  Note Type
4           Annuity 
1           Balance
NULL        Blank
3           Division
```

I suspect that my problem is in the `WHERE` clause which uses the `@NoteType` parameter to retrieve rows for the report.  Here's what I have tried:

`WHERE et.NoteValue = @NoteType`  -- works fine for @NoteType = 1, 3 or 4; but no rows are returned if @NoteType = NULL

`WHERE et.NoteValue = IIF(@NoteType IS NULL, NULL, @NoteType)`  -- same result

`WHERE et.NoteValue = CASE WHEN @NoteType IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @NoteType END`  -- same result (expected, since this is equivalent to the `IFF` version)

`WHERE et.NoteValue = COALESCE(@NoteType, et.NoteValue)`  -- works fine for `@NoteType = 1, 3 or 4`; but if `@NoteType = NULL` returns all rows with `NoteValue` column value 1, 3 or 4 but ***no rows*** with `NoteValue` column value = `NULL`

What `WHERE` clause should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your dataset for your main dataset is a dataset query (not a stored proc) then I would simply add a valid parameter value (I've used `0` in this exmaple)  to the parameter list and substitute that in the dataset query.

So, change the dataset query that provide parameter values to

```
SELECT      ett.NoteValue         AS    [Note Value],
            ett.NoteDescription   AS    [Note Type]
FROM        eventTextType    ett
UNION       
SELECT      0                     AS    [Note Value],
            'Blank'               AS    [Note Type]
ORDER BY    [Note Type]
```

Now in you main dataset query you can change your where clause to this (which will also handle multi-value parameters if that's required)

```
WHERE ISNULL(et.NoteValue, 0) IN(@NoteType)
```

Unless I've missed something obvious, that should be it.